# Converting a Edit Text to a double android

Tags: android, android-edittext, int, double

I have 2 edit texts and because I want to make them decimals I can not make them integers so I have to turn them into a double. I have this code but in the n2Var get text I have an error.

```
    mul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    n1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    n2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    ans = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.TextView10);

    double n1Var = Double.parseDouble(n1.getText().toString());
    double n2Var = Double.parseDouble(n2,getText().toString());
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have this in n2Var

```
 double n2Var = Double.parseDouble(n2,getText().toString());
```

instead of

```
 double n2Var = Double.parseDouble(n2.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 6):

in Kotlin you can use this..

```
edittext.text.toString().toDouble()
```